# Ajax form building in yii

Tags: php, ajax, forms, yii

In my view I have several buttons.
Now when user press them I want to tell server which button was pressed, then server to create form, then pass this html to my view, and place it in some specific div. Then depending on some selector changes in this form, I want the view to ask server again for some data, bring it back and pass it to some parts of this form.

I can do jquery ajax requests, using some php file on server side, and again jquery html manipulations when receive answer, but I thought maybe this things are done smarter in yii and there is some better practice of how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process will be the same pretty much as you would do without Yii. Obviously some of the methods will be Yii ones instead though.